# Is it good to use memcached in fully dynamic and heavy database website?

Tags: php, mysql, caching, memcached, query-builder

I'm currently working on the project which is like e-commerce site. There are hundreds of thousands of records in the database tables. I also have to use join operations on them to get data as there is **query builder** in project to select criteria of data. It takes too much time to fetch data. So, I'm using limit as some no of records(e.g. 10) per page. Now I come to know the concept of memcached. So I thought to use memcached for my project as it will take too much time for only once. But still there are some doubts.

1. Will **too many cache file** affect? I mean there will be too many files will be created as for **each page of each module, there will be one cache file**. So digit will go approx **10000 cache file**.
2. Let's assume that there is no any problem of no of files. But what about to **update files** using replace() when any row of table is being added or deleted from middle of the table. And here, **table is being updated near about every week**.

So I'm in dilemma that should I go for memcached or not? If any one can advice and answer with explanation, then it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your website executes many of the same MySQL queries that frequently return the same data, then yes, there is probably some benefit to running memcached.

**Problem:**

> > "There are hundreds of thousands of records...It takes too much time to fetch the data".

This probably indicates a problem with your schema.  Properly indexed, even when using JOINs, the queries should be able to execute quickly (< 0.1 seconds).  Run an `EXPLAIN` query on the queries that are taking a long time to run and see if they can be improved.

**Answer to Question 1**

There won't be an issue with too many cache files.  Memcached stores all cached information in memory (hence the name), so no disk files are used.  Cached objects are stored in RAM and accessed directly from RAM.

**Answer to Question 2**

Not exactly sure what you are asking here, but if your application updates or deletes information from the database, then it is critical that the cache items affected by the updates and deletes are deleted.  If the application doesn't remove cached items affected by such operations, than the next time the data is queried, cached results which are no longer valid may be returned.  Make sure any data cached either has appropriate expiration times set, or the application removes them from cache when the data in the database changes.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would start not from Memcached but from figuring out what the bottleneck is. Your tables have roughly one millions rows. I don't know the size of a row but my educated guess is that it is less than 1K based on the fact that a browser window accommodates information from one record.

So it is probably 1G of information in your database. Correct me if I'm wrong. If that's true then the whole database should be automatically cached in RAM by MySQL.

Now that your database is totally in RAM then with proper organization of indexes complexity of a query should be linear with respect to the number of the result set which measured in a number of kilobytes because it fits the browser window.

So my advice is to determine the size of the database and to see the result of "top" command in order to know how much memory is consumed by MySQL. And if you make sure that your database sits totally in memory then run the explain command against your most popular queries and add some indexes to your database according to the result of the explain. Even if your database is bigger than the amount of RAM then I still recommend you to look into the results of the explain command cause it really helps a lot.